# Selecting the other side of the object in a boolean operation

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to cut an object using a plane into two objects. I am using `difference` boolean modifier. How can I tell Blender which part I want and which part I don't want? I have no control on which part should remain after the boolean operation. Could someone help me on this?

**Update:** (for better illustration of the question). For example, let's say we have a cube which is cut by a plane. How can I selectively specify which part of the following cube should be removed after the boolean operation on the cube and the plane? For example, how can I remove part (1) of the cube instead of part (2)? I am trying to be able to tell Blender remove the part which I don't want.

I should say that the boolean modifier works perfectly with the plane being the cutter my object is splitted into a correct mesh. I would like to only be able to remove the other remaining object.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using `Difference` the other object is 'subtracted' from the one with the modifier. To get the other side you have to set the modifier to `Intersect`. This is the part where both objects overlap. The third option, `Union` would give you the boolean 'sum' of both objects.
In the image below the monkey head has the boolean modifier, the other object in the modifier is the cube.
[image]
BTW: notice the eye missing in the intersection case? The boolean modifier works on the object's volumes, but the monkey head is not a closed mesh, so the volume is not really defined. This may cause problems in some cases, so be aware of that.
EDIT: And as @stacker mentioned in the comments, since the boolean modifier works on the volume of the objects it might not work properly with a plane, at least when the edge of the plane is inside the volume of the other object.

**UPDATE**
There is no way to tell blender that it should take the other side of the object when using the boolean modifier set to `Difference`, since this is just the way the difference of two sets is defined: The difference of the sets A and B `A\B` are all points in A that are not in B. What points are in B is defined by the normal of your cutting plane; The normal points to the outside.
If you want the other half of the cube you have to flip the normal of the plane or set the boolean modifier to `Intersect`. The intersection of two sets A and B `A^B` is all points in A that are also in B. This is exactly the opposite of the difference.
[image]

Comment: You could add that this is performed using a cube and won't work with plane.

Comment: @maddin45: I have updated my question for better illustration.

Comment: @Ahm I've updated my answer accordingly. I hope this clears things up.